# What is a "Selective Query"

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

In database, I often hear "Selective Query"!
What do you call a "Selective Query"?

Is it the query that returns very tiny result set by looking up very huge tables?
Like,

```
SELECT * 
  FROM dbo.PurchaseOrder 
 WHERE PurchaseDate = '1/1/2018'
```

Like grabbing a small piece of rock from huge mountain.

Or is it the query that selects so many columns regardless of number of rows it returns?
Like,

```
SELECT col1, 
        ...,
       col30 
  FROM dbo.SomeWideTable
```

Please help me understand the terminology, with example if possible.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If db can get rows by testing a small number of rows then the query is selective.

DB can ignore large parts of the table is many circumstances, but most likely because there are fitting indexes. Columns that are part of predicates (where/having), have to be part of indexes. We use conditions that are index friendly (e.g. equality). Etc.

If query is not selective, then db have to scan more rows -> that's more IO -> that's slower read and maybe delay in some writes as table could be locked during those reads.

Sheer amount of fetched data is irrelevant. Columns not used in predicates may also not be included in indexes, then db uses indexes as a pointers to the table, and still just read the same amount of data (with just one extra read per each row in the results).

Comment: Ah ok - that's very interesting fact that I was not aware of.  So while executing a query, if it works with smaller amount of data to begin with then it's *selective*.  So seems like it's irrespective how many rows it returns - it's more how many rows it starts working with to begin with.  And indexing plays major role here, b/c it weeds out the rows the query is not interested in up front.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

A "selective" query refers to a query that selects few rows relative to the number of rows in the table.

In general, an index is useful on such a query, because it reduces the number of data pages that need to be read.

I am not aware that it refers to the number of columns referenced in the query, although there may be people who use it for such a purpose.

Comment: Thanks Gordon for the quick reply.  So a table contains 10 million rows.  Query1 does lookup the table based on an index and returns a few hundred rows.  Query2 pretty much does the same thing but returns a few thousand rows...so then we can say Query1 is *more selective* than Query2, correct?